# Where are the vases in this picture? A term for that space

Tags: word-request, terminology, image-identification

In my recently purchased apartment, I've come up with an idea for the hall as a part of interior designing. In my mother-tongue, we have **a term** for those three pits(?).

> Vases in the wall? - I'm *not* okay with it.

How do we describe this in English? Non native speakers? I'm searching for the term that *describes* those three (without vases). They are three ______ in/on the wall.

Here is the actual picture

[image: three vases]

Comment: All I can say is: It looks awesome!

Comment: Thanks @RuchirM. I just want to put this awesomeness in words explaining it to others without showing the picture! Any term for that?

Comment: Three vases in wall niches.

Comment: I agree with everyone else that "niche" is the right word. However, if you don't know this word, or think your listener may not know this word, I think *recess* (the noun) would work too. Common terms such as *recessed wall shelf/panel* would also work, IMHO. If a recess (or a niche) has a glass lid, I think we could also it a *recessed display case* or a *recessed showcase*.

Comment: True, the *noun* 'recess' is also a good choice. Another word found is - [*alcove*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/alcove?q=alcove) @DamkerngT.

Comment: @MaulikV but alcoves are larger - you typically can sit in an alcove but not necessarily in a niche.

Comment: True that. @Stephie not necessarily for the vases/statues but this gives a good term to interior designers

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Without expressing awesomeness, the term is

**[niche](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/niche)**

- a recess in a wall, especially for statues.

From the architectural feature the figurative meaning of "a special place" either in a professional, scientific or ecological context is derived.

Comment: "especially for statues" - wow!

Comment: @RobertGrant not my definition, for examples, see here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niche_(architecture)

Comment: I've seen "Recessed Shelf" and "alcove" used to describe this feature before - bout would concur with @Stephie that "Niche" is the correct term.

Comment: Not to take away too much from this answer, but I generally think of a niche going all the way to the floor.

Comment: @Daniel Please check the Wikipedia link in my comment above...

Answer (score 11):

A word that most people would be familiar with is **recess**, or more specifically in this case **a recessed shelf**.

> **recess** - [*from Dictionary.com*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/recess)
>   3. a receding part or space, as a bay or alcove in a room.
>   4. an indentation in a line or extent of coast, hills, forest, etc.

> **recess** - [*from Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recessg)
>   2. An inset, hole, space or opening.

Comment: The term _niche_ is spot on, but because the architectural definition is not widely known, I added this answer as well, which will be understood  by most English-speakers.

Comment: I noticed that the other answers—niche, alcove and nook—all use "recess" in their definition.

Answer (score 8):

This can also be referred to as an ***alcove***. Alcoves can also be an area you can walk into though, so be careful to avoid ambiguity.

> **alcove**
>
> /ˈalˌkōv/
>
> A recess, typically in the wall of a room or of a garden.
>
> *Origin: Late 16th century: from French alcôve, from Spanish alcoba, from Arabic al-ḳubba 'the vault'.*

*Source: [OxfordDictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/alcove)*

Answer (score 3):

Another potential word for this is **nook** though it's usually for a larger space.

> nook - [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nook)
>
> Noun, noo k
>
> 3. any small recess: a breakfast nook.

Generally the size progression is that a nook is bigger than an alcove which is bigger than a niche.  In this specific case I think you're referring to a niche, I place this answer here purely for the sake of completion.  The safest is definitely "recessed shelf" with a qualifier as to the desired dimensions of the space.